# prove a bounded and linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $Tx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_n \langle x,e_n\rangle e_n$ be bounded where $\{\lambda_n\}_n$ are the complex eigenvalues and $\{e_n\}_n$ are
an orthonormal basis of the separable space $H$. For any continuous function $f : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ define $f(T)(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f(\lambda_n) \langle x,e_n\rangle e_n$.
Prove that $f(T) : H \to H$ is a bounded linear operator.

Comment: The $\lambda_n$ are contained in a compact region of $\mathbb C$, where $f$ attains a maximum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It boils down that $\lambda _n$ must be bounded. Assume otherwise then you may choose a subsequence  $\lambda_{k_n}$ such that $ \sum_{n\geq 0} \lambda_{k_n}^{-2} $ converges.

Now choose that $x=\sum_{n\geq 0}\lambda_{k_n}^{-1} e_{k_n} $. Then $T(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} e_{k_n}$ which is not an element in $H$. So to have $T$ even make sense we need $\lambda _n$ to be bounded. Now it is not hard to see that if $\lambda _n$ are bounded then $T$ is continuous.

From here since the collection $\lambda _n $ lies in a bounded set of $\mathbb{C}$ and since $f$ is continuous so $f(\lambda _n)$ do.

And hence $f(T)$ is continuous.